# Fetching large amount of data with React native

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, performance, react-native, single-threaded

was working on a project that for some of the users, we need to fetch a large amount of data. It seems that it's fine on the simulator, but it can be pretty slow when running one a real iOS/iPhone device. Since react-native/js is single threaded, multithreading is probably not an option

was wondering what a good way might be to mitigate this

Answer (score 2):

was able to resolve the issue with `InteractionManager` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager Essentially it delays the long-running work to be scheduled after any interactions/animations have completed

```
componentDidMount() {

    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      // ...long-running synchronous task...
      fetch([url], {

      }).then((response) => {

      })
    })
```